# Different look of checkbox on device and emulator

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have list view with checkboxes. Problem is in different showing checkboxes on device and on emulator.

Here is how it looks in emulator:

[image]

and how it looks on device:

[image]

You can see that on device checkbox have cutted right edge.

This is @drawable/custom_checkbox_design.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />

</selector>
```

and layout for rows:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ColChk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColOpis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="Opis"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Code"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why on emulator is showed correctly?

Comment: Please try once, move images you are using to drawable-hdpi folder and check and let me know...

Comment: ok let me check another solution..

Comment: I used same code....But I am not getting any problem...
Please try once, change your both icons. Select this icons from adt-bundle(D:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\drawable-hdpi). And keep them in drawable-hdpi.
I gave you path may be it different in your PC.

Comment: try and let me know if any problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found proper solution.

Instead of

```
android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"
```

should be

```
 android:button="@null"
 android:background="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"
```

Answer (score 1):

The android UI system using XML is quite buggy. It differs significantly based on the version of android operating system you use. Usually emulator has latest android version while devices do not. There seems to be nothing wrong with your layout file just try changing the following values:

```
android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"
```

Try using different values for layout_marginRight and changing images of checkbox.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I've already tried that, doesn't help. The android versions are the same. Device is running 4.1.2 same as the emulator.

Comment: The interesting part is that when I using standard checkbox without graphic than works fine.